# .each() on JQuery Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a JQuery Dropdown similar to the one used in bootstrap.

The problem which arises is that when an individual list item is clicked, all sub navigation's display block.

Now I know this issue can be resolved with .each() but my code does not seem to work.

Please find the example here; http://jsfiddle.net/N7xgC/

Apologies if this question has already been asked before.

B

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I only want the .sub which relates to the relevant list item to open not every .sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification:

http://jsfiddle.net/N7xgC/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('.main > li > a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            // When the anchor is clicked, find the next .sub element and toggle it
            $(this).next('.sub').toggle();
        });
    });
});
```

I changed yours to toggle the element with the class `.sub` 'next' to the clicked anchor.

Comment: @17bc17 no problem, glad it was helpful :) If you did find it helpful, perhaps you could consider marking it as accepted?

Comment: you explained it dude so you deserve it

Comment: @17bc17 Fair enough :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select all `.sub` and toggle them. You need to get only the one next to the a-element that is clicked.

Try this instead:

```
$(this).next(".sub").toggle();
```

Updated your fiddle so you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/N7xgC/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main li a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.sub').toggle();
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/N7xgC/4/)